# Custom Database integration with MOSS 2007

Tags: database, sharepoint, excel, moss, integration

Hopefully someone has been down this road before and can offer some sound advice as far as which direction I should take. I am currently involved in a project in which we will be utilizing a custom database to store data extracted from excel files based on pre-established templates (to maintain consistency). We currently have a process (written in C#.Net 2008) that can extract the necessary data from the spreadsheets and import it into our custom database. What I am primarily interested in is figuring out the best method for integrating that process with our portal. What I would like to do is let SharePoint keep track of the metadata about the spreadsheet itself and let the custom database keep track of the data contained within the spreadsheet. So, one thing I need is a way to link spreadsheets from SharePoint to the custom database and vice versa. As these spreadsheets will be updated periodically, I need tried and true way of ensuring that the data remains synchronized between SharePoint and the custom database. I am also interested in finding out how to use the data from the custom database to create reports within the SharePoint portal. Any and all information will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually written a similar system in SharePoint for a large Financial institution as well.

The way we approached it was to have an event receiver on the Document library. Whenever a file was uploaded or updated the event receiver was triggered and we parsed through the data using [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx).

The key to matching data in the excel sheet with the data in the database was a small header in a hidden sheet that contained information about the reporting period and data type. You could also use the SharePoint Item's unique ID as a key or the file's full path. It all depends a bit on how the system will be used and your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be awkward.  The Business Data Catalog (BDC) functionality will enable you to tightly integrate with your database, but simultaneously trying to remain perpetually in sync with a separate spreadsheet might be tricky.  I guess you could do it by catching the update events for the document library that handles the spreadsheets themselves and subsequently pushing the right info into your database.  If you're going to do that, though, it's not clear to me why you can't choose just one or the other:

1. Spreadsheets in a document library, or
2. BDC integration with your database

If you go with #1, then you still have the ability to search within the documents themselves and updating them is painless.  If you go with #2, you don't have to worry about sync'ing with an actual sheet after the initial load, and you could (for example) create forms as needed to allow people to modify the data.

Also, depending on your use case, you might benefit from the MOSS server-side Excel services.  I think the "right" decision here might require more information about how you and your team expect to interact with these sheets and this data *after* it's initially uploaded into your SharePoint world.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Basically, the end goal is to have financial/data analysts be able to upload a spreadsheet, make changes to the data (as needed) and view reports based on the data they entered. Let me know if you need any further information. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How are those reports going to be generated?  Do they depend on any info other than the Excel sheets themselves?

Comment: The reports will be generated from the data in the custom database that has been extracted from the spreadsheets. I'm guessing we could employ SSRS within SharePoint in order to generate our reports. Also, just to clarify,the spreadsheets are currently stored within a document library in our portal.

Answer (score 0):

So... I'm going to assume that you are leveraging Excel because it is an easy way to define, build, and test the math required.  Your spreadsheet has a set of input data elements, a bunch of math, and then there are some output elements.  Have you considered using Excel Services?  In this scenario you would avoid running a batch process to generate your output elements.  Instead, you can call Excel services directly in SharePoint and run through your calculations.  More [information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms546696.aspx): available online.

You can also surface information in SharePoint directly from the spreadsheet.  For example, if you have a graph in the spreadsheet, you can link to that graph and expose it.  When the data changes, so does the graph.

There are also some High Performance Computing (HPC) Excel options coming out from Microsoft in the near future.  If your spreadsheet is really, really big then the Excel Services route might not work.  There is some information available online (search for HPC excel - I can't post the link).